# How do I do a post request to a Razor function in that is in the same cshtml document as my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, ajax, razor

I am trying to make a function call in a post-request with AJAX to a function I have defined in the  `@function{}`-tag to do a refresh of the page. I am trying to make a file upload function. This is my Razor function:

```
public string UploadFile(string filePath, string fileContent)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("uploads");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    container.SetPermissions(
        new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);
    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent)))
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
    string test = storageAccount.ToString();
    return filePath + " " + test + " " + fileContent;
}
```

How exactly do I make a function call when it is in the same document because of the way C1 CMS works?
I know I cannot make a simple function call since the server code is already rendered before the javascript is loaded. This is what i have so far in terms of my post request:

```
function postUpload(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@UploadFile("testFilePath","testData")',
        data: "",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to make a request to a separate location, not to a server-side function defined in the same page

Comment: Sadly the tool I am using to create my website doesn't allow it, unless it would work to call a method in a class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I changed my entire function in C1 CMS to a User Control Function instead. Then I separated the HTML and the code into two different files. Furthermore I converted most of the code to client-side, and set a value in a hiddenfield on postback in order to send the desired information to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just define the `UploadFile` function in your controller as an **AJAX** action?

There doesn't seem to be anything in your function that would require the server to know about what's happening on the client side.